# How do I add Chart.js into a custom plugin in Moodle?

Tags: php, chart.js, requirejs, moodle, amd

I am creating a custom plugin in Moodle and I have successfully integrated [Chart.js](https://www.chartjs.org/). It works perfectly in my development environment when the cache is disabled. But when I turn on my cache, the below error appears in the console.

[image]

[image]

local_mql is my custom plugin and the JavaScript file is added under *amd/src/mql.js* and the minified version is under *amd/build/mql.min.js*.

Below is my code.

```
requirejs.config({
    paths: {
        "chartjs": "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js@3.7.1/dist/chart.min"
    }
});

define(
[
    'jquery',
    'core/str',
    'core/ajax',
    'core/templates',
    'jqueryui',
    'core/modal_factory',
    'core/modal_events',
    'chartjs'
],
function (
    $,
    Str,
    ajax,
    templates,
    jqui,
    ModalFactory,
    ModalEvents,
    Chart
){});
```

What am I doing wrong? And how do I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
"chartjs": "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js@3.7.1/dist/chart.min"
```

It seems your path is wrong.
You are missing the file extension.

```
"chartjs": "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js@3.7.1/dist/chart.min.js"
```